# print out the total usable memory available

Tags: c

This is what I currently have but I'm doing it wrong. Can someone please explain how to format the output into GB? I have a total of 16GB of available ram and I'm getting an output of 62GB.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

int main(void) {
  struct sysinfo sys_info; // for system information
  sysinfo(&sys_info); // to get system information
  
  printf("Total usable memory size: %ldGB", sys_info.totalram / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell if this is a *formatting* question or a problem with your use of *sysinfo*, so you should really try troubleshoot it better.  The first step would be to simply print out sys_info.totalram without modifying it.  Make sure your code compiles without warnings and errors, and then show us what it prints.  If it prints the right value, then we know you have a formatting issue and we can focus on that.  If it prints the wrong value, then there is a problem with how you are using `sysinfo` and we can focus on that.

Comment: You should also print the `int` returned by `sysinfo`, since it indicates whether there was an error.

Comment: BTW: the `sysinfo` struct contains only unsigned members. Most of them `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that `sysinfo` will actually already give you the size in kB (KiloBytes). That means that you actually divide by `1000.0` to get GB (GigaByte). Also I think you would want your output to be double precision.

I modified your code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

int main(void) {

  struct sysinfo sys_info; // for system information
  sysinfo(&sys_info); // to get system information
  // note: %.3f is double precision but I only need to display 3 decimal places
  printf("Total usable memory size       : %.3fGB", sys_info.totalram / 1000.0 / 1000.0 / 1000.0);


  return 0;
}
```

Don't be confused when you try to verify this using `cat /proc/meminfo`. This is actually displaying the total memory in KibiBytes. One KibiByte is 1.024 KiloByte. You can do the math and it will also end up in the same solution.